# Python slicing,index and print function?1

Tags: python, algorithm

This question is originally a homework that i have been trying to resolve, i know that i need to use slicing and index and for loops in order to do it right, i have been writing algorithms but non is right, I'm asking for a hint regarding the correct algorithm, this algorithm below is only a part of the code and of course the if statement is not correct, because the string is given by user it makes the algorithm tricky.

(Write a program that asks the user to enter two strings, `r1` and `r2`. It should compute and display the following information: number of positions in the strings that have the same letter, number of letters from string `r1` that are also in `r2`.)

```
r1 = input ("Enter a string") r2 = input ("Enter a string")

po_ctr = 0 le_ctr = 0

if r2[::] in r1[::]:
    print (Sr[1:])
```

The other issue I'm facing is with the print function, I already wrote another program about divisors and multipliers of a number but what should by printed is (numbers are: (the numbers on one line) what happened is i tried the `print (d,end="")` but it's printing the (numbers are) repeatedly as well.

```
for d in range(N_small, N_big+1, N_small):print ("The numbers are :",d,end="")
```

Comment: You need to fix the code at the end. Indent all code 4 spaces to begin with too so it's styled as code.

Answer (score 0):

For the printing of your numbers, try adding all your numbers into a single string, and at the end of your for loop, printing out the entire string. for actually finding the letters in your strings, you could use a loop such as:

```
for item in r1:
    #Do something with the letter 'item'
```

Example:

```
for item in "Hello":
    print(item)
#Output:
#H
#E
#L
#L
#O
```